# Complex Regex composition - Regex that match "if"

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm making a Regex to match hashtags to my project. I want that regex match hashtags that are separeted by one single space, don't have another hashtag inside this content **and just match a space in the string if this is followed by any word** (except other blank space or #).

I'm really curious to know if I can do something like "if" in regular expressions and I hope you can help me with this.

**So, in:**

```
"#hashtag?!-=_"  "#hashhash#"  "#hash tag"  "#hash  tag"  "#hash #ahuhuhhuasd" "#hash "
```

**The regex must match the following sentences:**

```
"#hashtag?!-=_" "#hashhash" "#hash tag" "#hash" "#hash #ahuhuhhuasd" "#hash"
                            (all hashtag)        (one)  (another h.)
```

### Actually, this is my code:

```
#{1,1}\S+\s{0,1}
```

You can test [here](http://rubular.com/) this code, but it matches things that isn't desired:

```
"#ahusdhuas?!__??###hud #ahusdhuads "  
The blank space in the end of the string, the 3 '#' inside the string. 
none of the following content is desired in this string, just "#ahusdhuas?!__??"
```

Glad if you can help me!

Comment: What flavor of regex? Ruby?

Comment: I'm using Rubular to test the regex, but I will use it in JavaScript. It's a problem?

Comment: Yes, it's a problem.  Different flavors have different capabilities, e.g. JavaScript can't do negative lookbehinds but Ruby can.

Comment: You said in your question _"hashtags that are separeted by one single space,'_ and in the end you say that you want just "#ahusdhuas?!__??" in  "#ahusdhuas?!__??###hud #ahusdhuads " that is not separated by a blank from "###hud #ahusdhuads "

Comment: In future please tag your question with the language(s) you're using, not just what you're trying to do. 'Regex'by itself is almost meaningless, unless you're asking a question about the concept, or task itself, and not an implementation.

Comment: @FernandoPaladini Hello, I have an answer. Please, see it and say me what don't fit what you want. Because I still have some lack of comprehension of certain points. **1/** Do you know that writing ``"#hashtag?!-=_" "#hashhash#" "#hash tag"`` in a code is interpreted in such a manner that it results in the string ``"#hashtag?!-=_#hashhash##hash tag"`` ? Then these hashtags aren't separated by one blank, in fact.

Comment: @FernandoPaladini **2/** _"hashtags that are separated by one single space"_ Is it really what you want ? If so, the match in ``"#ahusdhuas?!__??###hud #ahusdhuads "`` must be ``"#ahusdhuads"`with the "d", not ``"#ahusdhuas?!__??"`` nor the ``"#ahusdhuas"`` in it **3/** Does the sentence beginning with **The blank space in the end of the string, the 3 '#' inside...** really needs to be in a code's frame ? I hesitate to edit this point.

Comment: @FernandoPaladini **4/** In the string ``ab #has ht ag cut #hush``, is the hashtag to be matched this one ``#has ht`` or this one ``#has ht ag cut`` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need :

```
(#(?:\s?[^#\s]+)+)
```

Here are some tests :

[image]

Comment: It's really perfect, but it just detects the first "#". If I type something like "asdhuahsdhads #hashtag   #hashtag203", this only match the first hashtag: "#hashtag". Do you know what's the issue? If you solve that I will be very glad :)

Comment: I just forget to insert /g before your regex. It work's perfectly. For those who're interested, this is the final regex: "/(#(?:\s?[^#\s]+)+)/g". Thanks for everyone that answer this question, I will give all a vote up. And to @Emil I will give the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
#[^# ]+(?: [^# ]+)*
```

Match a `#`, then one or more characters that aren't `#` or , then 0 or more instances of ( A space followed by one or more characters that aren't `#` or ).  The ?: makes the group non-capturing.

If you don't want to match `###hud` in `#ahusdhuas?!__??###hud #ahusdhuads` at all because it begins with three `#`, you can add the negative lookbehind: `(?<!#)` to the front of the regex:

```
(?<!#)#[^# ]+(?: [^# ]+)*
```

However, that will work in Ruby but not in JavaScript, since JavaScript doesn't have the capability to do lookbehinds.  In that case you'd have to use the `#[^# ]+(?: [^# ]+)*` pattern, and if the match starts after the first character, test the previous character in the string in your code to see if it is a `#`, and if so, reject the match the regex returns.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and sorry for slow reply. Well, your regex just capture two characters, I don't know why. If I type: "#hashtag", just "#ha" is captured. Do you know what's the issue?

Comment: I usually use .NET to test regular expressions, and I didn't have any particular problems with http://rubular.com/ (though it would only accept fixed-width lookbehinds).  I also tried http://regexpal.com/ which can test JavaScript regexes (You should test using this one, not Rubular), and that didn't have any problem with the first (non-lookbehind) pattern, though it did give an error on the lookbehind `(?<!#)` as I expected.  Have a look at my edits above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies Monty Wild, you really helped me. I will give you some points - you'll understand soon.

Comment: Fernando Paladini, Thank you for the thought, but serial upvoting is considered voting fraud and gets reversed.  However, if you really want to give me some points, you can start a bounty and award me the points: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Answer (score 1):

Is any of these are what You've been looking for?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer man!! I think your code is exactly what I need, but this isn't working in JavaScript. I got the following error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<=")#[^ #"]+(?:\s(?=[^ #])|)/: Invalid group" Can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't recognize the `(?<=`...`)` group, which is a lookbehind.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it, though I'm not accustomed to Javascript's regex expression because I only use Python.
I tested the following on the site [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/) given by Monty Wild, it's the only one that showed me all the substrings matched:

```
(?:^ |^| )(#[^#\s]+(?: [^#\s]+)?)(?:(?=\Z| \Z| \S)| +(?=#))
```

result

```
#hashtag?!-=_
#hash tag
#hash
#ahuhuhhuasd
#hash
```

As Javascript's regexex doesn't accept lookbehind assertions, I used a trick to make so that a hastag preceded by two or more blanks won't match: these preceding blanks are consumed by the regex machine as subsequent blanks in the preceding matching: that's the role of the last part `+(?=#)` of the regex to trihgger such a matching of trailing blanks of a matcjing if there are more than one. This cosumption intervenes only if the former part `(?=\Z| \Z| \S)` didn't match

Answer (score 1):

Tried this in a standard HTML page and in Firebug as well ...

Works againt inputs you gave.

```
var hashTags = ["#hashtag?!-=_", "#hashhash#", "#hash tag", "#hash  tag", "#hash #ahuhuhhuasd", "#hash ", "#hash #", "#foo bar baz"];
hashTags.forEach(function(el, idx, arr) {
    console.log( el.match(/#([^#\s]|(( [^\s])(?!\s|$)))+/g));
});

// Console output
> ["#hashtag?!-=_"]
> ["#hashhash"]
> ["#hash tag"]
> ["#hash"]
> ["#hash #ahuhuhhuasd"]
> ["#hash"]
> ["#hash"]
> ["#foo bar baz"]
```

Comment: Thanks, but Emil Davtyan already solved my question. (and I can't match any results with your regex :/ )

Comment: @FernandoPaladini I regret you're not able to take advantage of this reg-ex. I might not be aware of all possible cases. Could you just tell which string does not match ? thank you

Comment: I really don't know. I just insert your regex in my function and this doesn't works - doesn't match any #. :/